# Query to show when the discount line item is used in a sales order, but still display all sales orders

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a query that displays (to keep it simple): CompanyID, CompanyName, SalesOrderID, Discount Amount, SalesOrder Total, In this case, the only way to get the discount amount would be to query for the item we use for adding a discount by the sales team. I'd like to return null or 0 if it doesn't exists in the sales order OR return the value(dollar amount applied to the discount) if it was used. The only thing I know is to use a simple where clause, which excludes the sales orders that don't have that item in the item detail. The table I have access to are CompanyTable, SalesOrder table that has the total but not a discount amount, and SalesDetail table that show the items in the Salesorder.

Any help would be appreciated, I feel like there's a function that could do it I'm just lost.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: What I am looking to get is CompanyName, SalesOrderID, SalesOrderTotal, DiscountAmount.

The first three are fields that are easy to grab, the last one I have to look through a SalesOrderDetail table to find if the discount item was used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use conditional aggregation.  It is unclear what you mean by "value".  But for instance, you can get the total amount for the order and then the total amount for the item using something like this:

```
select salesorderid, sum(price) as total_price,
       sum(case when itemid = ? then price end) as item_total
from orderlines
group by salesorderid;
```

Comment: Here what I used and it worked. Thanks so much for your help. Remember anyone reading to list all of your columns in the Group By! 

Select l.LocationName,
  s.CreatedDated,
  s.Total,
  sum(case when sd.ItemID = '0943049584958948549' then Dollar Else 0 End) as Discount
 from QBIntegration.SalesOrder s with (nolock)
  Join Location.Location l on s.BillToLocationID = l.locationid
  Join QBIntegration.SalesOrderDetail sd on s.SalesOrderID = sd.SalesOrderID
 where s.InstallOn between '1/1/2020' and '12/31/2020'
 Group by LocationName, Total, InstallOn